# OpenCV: subtract same BGR values from all pixels

Tags: opencv

I have some BGR image:

```
cv::Mat image;
```

I want to subtract from all the pixels in the image the vector:

```
[10, 103, 196]
```

Meaning that the blue channel for all the pixels will be reduced by 10, the green by 103 and the red by 196.

Is there a standard way to do that, or should I run for loops over all the channels and all the pixels?

Comment: Yes, [subtract](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract) a scalar from that `Mat` or use a [`matrix expression`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions) to achieve the same. | " should I run for loops" if you're tempted to do that, peruse the documentation -- in vast majority cases (especially for something as trivial as your case) it's unnecessary and sub-optimal (as OpenCV is likely to contain a vectorized and parallelized implementation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

suppose we have image that all channels filled with zero and for instance it's dimension is 2x3

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(2,3,CV_32SC3)
```

output will be:

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

then if we want to add or subtract a singleton variable, then we can use `cv::Scalar`

1- suppose we want to add `3` in blue channel:

```
image = image + Scalar(3,0,0);  // the result will be same as image=image+3;
```

with above code our matrix is now:

```
[3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0;
 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

2- if you want to add to another channel you can use second or third argument(or forth) of `cv::Scalar` like below

```
image = image +Scalar(3,2,-3);
```

output will be

```
[3, 2, -3, 3, 2, -3, 3, 2, -3;
 3, 2, -3, 3, 2, -3, 3, 2, -3]
```

### Using `cv::subtract`

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(2,3,CV_32SC3);
subtract(image,Scalar(2,3,1),image);
```

output

```
[-2, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1;
 -2, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1]
```

Comment: "this is nice question" -- IMHO this question is a nice example of low research effort. I just don't understand how this "using library without reading the docs (or source if docs are lacking)" thing works... maybe I've been doing things the hard way :D | Your answer would be a lot better if you used proper sentences (capitalization, punctuation) and provided some links to the docs of the data structures and functions you're referring to.